# how to replicate Failed parsing field: content org.mule.runtime.core.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have an API that is using GET method to get status of an order ./status/orderId/123456
123456 is a path parameter that we need to pass.

Sometimes in mule log I am seeing below error, but not sure the cause of error:

> Failed parsing field: content org.mule.runtime.core.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException: "org.mule.weave.v2.exception.UnexpectedFunctionCallTypesException: You called the function 'AnonymousFunction' with these arguments:   1: String ("123456" as String {class: "java.lang.String"})   2: Null (null) But it expects arguments of these types:   1: Any   2: String   3: Object 17|

How to reproduce this type of error?

Comment: In your dataweave, you have to mention default "" if the value does not exists.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the complete error, the expression or component that is throwing the error (as XML text) and the input to that expression.

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because your script is trying to use some value that is null. You didn't provide all details for reproduction but most likely the issue is in this expression:

```js
write(inputData,inputData.^mimeType)
```

Probably `inputData.^mimeType` is returning null. You can reproduce the issue like this:

```js
write(payload,null)
```

I would recommend to rewrite that expression and use an explicit argument for the format. What you are using may not be returning the value you are expecting.